# Copying all files of specific type to a specific folder using Mac's Terminal

Tags: bash, copy-paste

How can I copy all files of specific type to a specific folder using Mac's Terminal.

```
find . -name '*.STY' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' /usr/bin/rsync -avR "{}" "./styleFiles_chekad/"
```

Above shell script does the job and keeps the folders intact. What if I don't want the subfolders and want to have all the files right in the "styleFiles_chekad"? However, it is very complicated. Is there an easier way to do this? The following command does not work!

```
cp . -name '*.STY' styleFiles_chekad/
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS. Anyone can recommend a good resource for bash scripting?

Comment: I found ["From Bash to Z Shell”](http://www.bash2zsh.com) to be very good, but I think ["Unix Power Tools (3rd Edition)”](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596003302.do) is the definitive reference (as much as any book can be considered as such in this day and age. I think it’s like 1200 pages. Zsh as the default shell in MacOS Catalina makes it a good tool to focus on, and the [Zsh mailing list](http://zsh.sourceforge.net) is a great and helpful place to seek help. I’ve been on the list since the 90s, I think.

Comment: O'Reilly Classic Shell Scripting is ... well, a classic.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just run

```
t=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/target
mkdir "$t"

find . -type f -name '*.STY' -exec cp {} "$t"/ \;

mv "$t"/* ./styleFiles_chekad/
rmdir "$t"
```

The idea behind using a temporary directory is to prevent `find` from also copying the files it already moved into `./styleFiles_chekad/`.